# Custom filters inside a specific category?

Tags: categories, filters

I have different categories that require different filters

For example a 'training' can be about a specific bodypart, by a specific athlete,..

What I want is something like this: [image]

But different versions of this for different categories.

I'm fairly new to wordpress development, but I have everything set up, made my own theme. The only thing left are these custom fiters.

How exactly should I accomplish this? 
Could I for example use custom filters to say: "Body part: shoulder", and then create a filter on custom fields inside a category?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these should be separate taxonomies. Category is actually a taxonomy in its own right.

You would create a taxonomy for each of the filters/drop-downs. This may seem like overkill but i think it will make it easier to work on additional features down the road.

Add the following method to your functions.php. Replace 'rwc' with your theme's domain:

```
function add_taxonomy($singular, $plural, $objects) {
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( $plural, 'General Name', 'rwc' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( $singular, 'Singular Name', 'rwc' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( $plural, 'rwc' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent '.$singular.':', 'rwc' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All '.$plural, 'rwc' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View '.$singular, 'rwc' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New '.$singular, 'rwc' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New '.$singular, 'rwc' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit '.$singular, 'rwc' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update '.$singular, 'rwc' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search '.$plural, 'rwc' ),
    'not_found'           => __( $singular.' Not found', 'rwc' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( $singular.' Not found in Trash', 'rwc' ),
);             
    $args = array(
      'hierarchical'        => true,
      'labels'              => $labels,
      'show_ui'             => true,
      'show_admin_column'   => true,
      'query_var'           => true,
      'rewrite'             => array('slug' => strtolower($singular))
    );
    register_taxonomy(strtolower($singular), $objects, $args);        
}
```

Then use it to add taxonomies. Replace 'post' with 'page' if you are looking to filter pages

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
    $objects = array('post');

    add_taxonomy('Gender', 'Genders', $objects);
    add_taxonomy('Level', 'Levels', $objects);
    // .. and so on
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! 
I've never worked with taxonomies before, anything specific I should know/read before I add your code? How do I assign posts to a taxonomy in the post editor? (sorry for all the questions)

Comment: The only thing i can think of that may be affected by this is the structure of your permalinks. So that is something to consider if you are using %category% in your permalink structure. For instance, with categories only (no new taxonomy) you could build hierarchical urls such as this: female/advanced/some-athlete/triceps.  I don't think you can get the same thing using custom taxonomies out of the box. I'm sure there are ways around that though.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. How would I let the taxonomies display as dropdowns in a specific category page?

Comment: Check out the wp_dropdown_categories function: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories. You would call it for each dropdown (with the taxonomy name: 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name-here'). You can also check out the source for it in wp-includes/category-template.php

Comment: Then here is an example for querying using multiple taxonomies/selections: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-multiple-post-type-with-multiple-taxonomies